# Using the Node Request module with AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, node-request

This lambda function works:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const done = (err, res, func) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: '200',
    body: res,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  })

  done(null, 'works'))
}
```

I can hit the API Gateway end point and receive the response message, `'works'`.

However, when I add a request call (`POST`ing a message to Slack) that looks like this:

```
const request = require('request')
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  // the json object is built following these docs:
  // https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments
  const SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL = process.env.SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL
  const uri = SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL
  const method = 'POST'
  const options = {
    json,
    uri,
    method,
  }

  const slack = (opts) => {
    request.post(opts, (err, response, body) => {
      if (response.statusCode < 300) {
        return 'Success!'
      } else {
        return 'Err!'
      }
    })
  }

  const done = (err, res, func) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: '200',
    body: res,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  })

  done(null, slack(options))
}
```

The server hangs when I hit the API end point ...

And I get a `Task timed out after 10.00 seconds` error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-06-23T16:41:21.483Z c385e32e-5832-11e7-8c4f-673b524cf783 Task timed out after 10.00 seconds"
}
```

But my Slack `POST` request gets sent and I see the message in the channel.

How do I send the `POST` request and then wait for it to return, and then exit the lambda function with a custom response message?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the callback into the callback of the `post` method

```
request.post(opts, (err, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode < 300) {
        return callback(null, {
            statusCode: '200',
            body: res,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        });
    } else {
        return callback(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just now tried that but still get the Timeout error even if I construct the function like that. Thx for taking the time to help tho! Appreciate it.

Comment: Did you remove the `done(null, slack(options))` part?

Comment: still getting the timeout error, here's my full source code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d40a8aee734f284c87646e222024fde7

Comment: Is your Lambda configured with a VPC?

Comment: Is it probably a private VPC without internet access?

Comment: the POST message is sent to Slack tho ... I can see it in the channel ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147485/discussion-between-maikay-and-seanplusplus).

Comment: This is the correct answer ... I had a bad image url in the slack webhook and the slack api was hanging on that ...